# To have something same as someone's or someone?

Tags: grammar

- I have the same car as my father.
- I have the same car as my father's. (as I am talking about my father's car)

I want to say my father and I have the same kind of car. which of these two structures are grammatically correct?

Comment: My car is the same colour as my father's [car is] _but_ I have the same car as my father [does].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option--

> I have the same car as my father.

--is correct. The conjunction "as" correlates "I" with "my father."

A clearer way to write the sentence may be:

> My car is the same kind as my father's.

or

> My car is the same model as my father's.

For further reference, see: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives/same-similar-identical.

Comment: You might also point out explicitly that *My* correlates with *father's* in the same way as *I* with *father*.